# Is there anything that can be done with a potion that you can't do with an enchanted item?

Tags: dresden-files

Enchanted items -- at least defensive ones -- can be activated for free, not requiring you to use an action.  As far as I'm aware, you can't do that with potions.  You have to use an action (or at least a supplemental) to drink them.

So is there anything you can do with a potion that can't be done via a magic item?  Only thing I can come up with is give the potion away, which takes a fate point or an additional item slot to do with an enchanted item.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As far as spell effects, no.  Any particular spell you can construct can be put either into an enchanted item or into a potion.

As far as game mechanics, potions are flexible filler.  They may take up a precious enchanted item slot, it may be single-use, but since they take a matter of hours to craft, by the rules you can also re-invent them for every session (as opposed to Ozark folk art or blasting rods, which take weeks into months).  You can also leave it open to later good effect - the potion effect doesn't have to be set at start of session, and when you need one really good free spell, a player can suddenly and dramatically remember what he had prepared that morning for just such an occasion...

And yes, like candy, they can be handed out.  They can have great use.  Just depends on how you prefer to play.